# R nonstandard evaluation: pass the name of a variable as a parameter to a function and have the function assign a value to it

Tags: r, function, non-standard-evaluation

I am certain this is answered somewhere, but was unable to find it. [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) also doesn't give the answer.

I need to pass the name of a variable as a parameter to a function and have the function assign a value to it.

```
assign_x <- function(xf = x){
  xf <- 5
}
rm(x)
assign_x(x)
x
```

Use Case:

I want to write a wrapper to odbc::dbConnect where I check to see if the connection is already valid and recycle the connection if needed.  Sometimes I need to disconnect then reconnect to get the connection to work properly if the query hangs on me.

Comment: `x` is local, maybe assign it to `.Globalenv`? I naively cannot see how you can  get  local `x` by simply calling `assign_x`.

Comment: This is probably not what you need but try it `assign_x <- function(xf = x){
  xf <- 5
  x <- deparse(substitute(x))
  assign(x,xf,envir = .GlobalEnv)
}`. It doesn't make sense to define `assign_x` that uses `assign`(frowned upon) anyways..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent.frame()` to assign in, well, the caller's environment.

```
assign_x <- function(xf = 'x', value = 5){
  x <- deparse(substitute(xf))
  assign(x, value, envir = parent.frame())
}

rm(x)
```

> Warning message:
>   In rm(x) : object 'x' not found

```
assign_x(x)
x
#[1] 5

assign_x(y, pi)
y
#[1] 3.141593
```

Comment: That answer works.  After researching: assign_x <-function(value = 5){value} x <-assign()  would be better.  But I am trying to run dbConnect in Rstudio and the "Connections" panel tab doesn't show a connection unless it is run in the global environment.